# What is the difference between \str_case:Nn and \str_case:Vn?

Tags: expl3, latex3

In expl3, the `\str_case:Nn` and `\str_case:Vn` variants are both pre-generated. In the interface3 document, it looks as though the `\str_case:Vn` variant were automatically generated from the `\str_case:nn` variant, whereas the `\str_case:Nn` variant seems to be its own separate implementation. Is there any difference in semantics or speed between the two variants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me do

```bash
latexdef str_case:Nn str_case:Vn
```

The output is

```
\str_case:Nn:
\long macro:->\exp_args:NV \str_case:nn

\str_case:Vn:
\long macro:->\exp_args:NV \str_case:nn
```

so the two functions are exactly the same.

The `Nn` variant got added recently for consistency.

Comment: `\str_case:Nn` was added not long ago: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1071

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, I forgot about that one. But in the same vein we should also add `\tl_if_blank:NTF` besides `\tl_if_blank:VTF`.

Comment: Indeed, good point

Comment: Thank you. How did I not know about `latexdef` for the past 10 years?

Comment: @Witiko `latexdef` was added in TeX Live 2017; previously one had to call it `texdef -t latex` (which is still possible). The “long” form is necessary if you want to test other engines, such as `xelatex` or `lualatex`. A gift of our former moderator Martin Scharrer.

Comment: @egreg Much appreciated. I am [rewriting the Markdown package into expl3 from grounds up](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/124) and I am having quite a lot of fun, but there's still a lot of trial and error involved. Tools like `latexdef` are a tremendous help.